# What usually happens when you don't define a div width?

Tags: html, css, width

**The Context**

Usually, when I want a `div` to fill up the horizontal space, I would use `width:100%`

However, on one of my pages, the `width:100%` tag would expand the page horizontally, resulting in a column of blank space to the right, and a scrollbar would appear on the x-axis.

I suspect this is because of `padding` in some of the sub divs.

Anyway, the problem seemed to be fixed when I removed the `width:100%` from the div style. So I end up with this:

```
<div style="background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);padding:8px;"><h1>smelle ;)</h1><?php include("navbar.php"); ?></div>
```

The page returned to normal, the div continued to fill up the entire horizontal length of the page, and there was no more gap to the right.

**My question is...**

In my current code, there is nothing that defines the width of the div, yet it continues to fill up the horizontal length.

It works fine, and I've tried it with several browsers. I'm just worried that it could result in problems in the future, or when an older browser is used.

Can anyone tell me if this is fine or should I do something about it?

Comment: Find a detailed explanation of your problem, why it occurs, and how you can solve it in my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not adding a width is correct.

## Why?

There is no need to modify the width at all if "100%" is what you want since this is the standard behaviour of so-called **block-level elements** (elements which have `display: block;`, be it per default or per manual assignment in CSS): they grab as much space as they can get horizontally.

The behaviour with the scrollbar results from your `padding: 8px` on the **outer** div. The standard **box-model** defines width as the *inner* width of an element, on which you have to add left and right paddings and border to find out the *actual* width of the element.

If you want to avoid this problem in the future, you can apply

```
html { 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
}

*, *:after, *:before {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

on the very top of your first loaded CSS stylesheet. This makes it so that padding kind of becomes "inner padding". Same with borders. Borders and paddings no longer add to the dimensions of an element, but happen on the inside. This is the box-model that old Internet Explorers have been using. The `box-sizing` property allow you to use it in modern browsers as well. `content-box` is the former so-called W3C box model (default in all browsers unless you specifiy something else), what old IEs used is now called `border-box`. This image shows it (the article that uses the picture is so out-dated I don't want to link to it):

[image]

Find a short video that explains the box-model (which is absolutely vital if you want to do webdesign) here:

> https://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/how-to/understanding-the-box-model.html

Comment: Wow, that's very informative! Thank you, I will definitely use this in the future!

Answer (score 1):

It's fine. The default value for `width` in a `div` is `auto`.

It works pretty much as `width: 100%` in that it will make the `div` take up the full width of the parent. The difference is that it will include borders and padding in the width, so if you have those the outer width won't be wider than the parent.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `padding:8px;` for the outer div. So when `width:100%;` given, there will be 8px extra on left and right, which causes scroll.

You can include the padding also to the width by specifying `box-sizing: border-box;`

Padding for sub divs as you mentioned is not the problem. Also if total width of sub divs is more than the window size, it may also cause the scroll.

When avoiding width, div will always fill the entire width unless you specify `float` or `position` properties

Answer (score 0):

I think reason is if the div is declared with no width 
it will act like it has width:auto;
means it will depend on its content that is why it will expand horizontally since you don't put specific width on it;

like this example below;

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
    <meta name="author" content="lolkittens" />

    <title>Untitled 5</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">          
the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog near the river bankthe quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog near the river bankthe quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog near the river bankthe quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog near the river bankthe quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog near the river bankthe quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog near the river bank                
</div>  
<body>
</html>
```

hope this can help with your understanding